# How to find column number when an element is found in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read an excel file in a pandas data frame. I am iterating over the indexed column comparing each of the element of the row with some value. When I find a match I need to find the column number in which the match is found.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C' : [5,7,2,5]})
print df

    A  B  C
 0  0  1  5
 1  0  2  7
 2  2  3  2
 3  1  4  5
```

If i find a match for element 3, I should be able to print 'B' along with B's column number i.e. 1.
How to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for da in df.index.values:
   for i,d in df.loc[data].items():
     print i
```

Here `i` will print the column number.

Comment: Yes! Dead on! That's the precise thing. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhijitGhate forgive me but I'm really confused as to what you find in this answer.  All it does is print every column name and value.  It doesn't get you what you asked for.

Comment: @piRSquared : After second loop you can insert any comparison. My Bad. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.where`.  It'll give you the row and corresponding column positions for all matches

```
i, j = np.where(df.values == 3)

j

array([1])
```

If you want the column labels

```
df.columns[j]

Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Much better solution as looping ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be multiple match, so is possible filter with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one match and then get `index` of `s` for all `True`s and select first value by `[]` For positions by column name use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
s = (df == 3).any()
print (s)   
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool

a = s.index[s]
print (a[0])
B

print (df.columns.get_loc(a[0]))
1
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C' : [5,2,3,5]})
print (df)
  A  B  C
0  0  1  5
1  0  2  2
2  2  3  3
3  1  4  5

s = (df == 3).any()
print (s)  
A    False
B     True
C     True
dtype: bool

a = s.index[s]
print (a)
Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')

print (df.columns.get_indexer(a))
[1 2]
```

Comment: The answer helps but i'm facing a scenario where data frame is `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C' : [5,2,3,5]})` . Also i need to write minimum possible iterations.

Comment: @AbhijitGhate - what is expected output?

Comment: `df.columns.get_indexer(a)` is the right path. But i am trying to avoid the iteration that i'll need to do on it to get those indexes separately. The answers helps to move forward though.

Comment: @AbhijitGhate - exactly, there are not loops.

Comment: @AbhijitGhate - I am really confused - so need loop solution with for? How do you think avoid iteration?

Comment: as it turns out, i need to write a n-squared code any way. The solution above definitely works for my case.